# Laravel update form date and time

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a form to update deadline where I need to edit the date and time. Also I want the form to have a calendar. I want to add the default value with calendar option

I am having the deadline as this format n database `2019-04-25 00:00:00`

Here is the code I made to add the calendar:

**View with the calendar**

```php
{{ Form::label('Abstracts Submission Deadline', 'Abstracts Deadline') }}
{{ Form::input('dateTime-local','Abstracts', $rss->Abstract_Submission_Deadline, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>$rss->Abstract_Submission_Deadline ]) }}
```

**View without the calendar**

```php
{{ Form::label('Ranking Deadline', 'Ranking Deadline') }}
{{ Form::text('Ranking', $rss->Ranking_Deadline, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => $rss->Ranking_Deadline ] ) }}        `
```

The first box I have the calendar without the default value, the second one I have the default value without the calendar

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to have the default value with the calendar option @Styx

Answer (score 0):

Use value attribute instead of placeholder.

Comment: https://codepen.io/th3vic/pen/JVGvzW I made this fork for you, it is not about Laravel, it is more about JS. Check it.